# How to prove (or disprove) a non-negative r.v. with finite expectation also have finite second moment?

Tags: probability

The problem is formulated as follows.
If $X$ is a non-negative random variable and $EX<\infty.$

Is it true that $EX^2<\infty?$

It seems that squaring wouldn't make much difference because $X$ is non-negative. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not hold in general.

Define $X$ by 
$$
\mathbb P(X=n)=\frac C{n^3},
$$
for $n\ge1$ and $C>0$ a normalizing constant.

Then, $\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac C{n^2}<+\infty$, but 
$$
\mathbb E[X^2]=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac C{n}=+\infty.
$$